# doGet method is called twice in a servlet running in tomcat 7 and created with IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I have created a simple servlet with only one System.out.println() method in doGet body, but when I am running it inside Tomcat 7 using IntelliJ Idea 12 I get the message that System.out.println() method prints twice.

This is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <description>A simple servlet</description>
        <display-name>SimpleServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.skiabox.myservlet.SimpleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SimpleServletPath</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is SimpleServlet.java :

```
package org.skiabox.myservlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello from GET method.");
    }
}
```

This is SimpleServletProject.iml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="web" name="Web">
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <deploymentDescriptor name="web.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
        </descriptors>
        <webroots>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web" relative="/SimpleServletProject" />
        </webroots>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Tomcat 7.0" level="application_server_libraries" />
  </component>
</module>
```

..and this is an image of Tomcat 7 settings :

[image: Tomcat settings]

Comment: It happens because IDEA queries the URL in the run configuration after starting the server to check that application deployment was successful.

Comment: What is the http request from browser? What do you do?

Comment: The browser url is http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletPath

Comment: @CrazyCoder So how do I fix that?

Comment: You fix that by putting different URL for the `Startup page`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've done that but now servlet does not execute at all.

Comment: ..and it is normal, since how you will execute it without calling its mapping url!

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the url mapping to / and now I have both my simple jsp page running at `http://localhost:8080/SimpleServerProject` and my servlet running the doGet method just once!

Comment: Could you update this with an example please?  I think I'm running into the same problem, but I don't know how to actually resolve the issue!