# Servlet abnormal invoking

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet:

```
@WebServlet ("/*")
public class X extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why it prints "1" twice. Who can explain that?

Output:
1
1

Comment: In what environment you are working?

Comment: Yes I have the same issue. It appear when you are running the application inside IDEA, not in external one. And auto-run(auto request) is enabled when you start tomcat. Try disable autorun web app settings and this will disappear.

Comment: Take a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444128/doget-method-is-called-twice-in-a-servlet-running-in-tomcat-7-and-created-with-i

Answer (score 1):

You can print out

```
request.getRequestURI()
```

to confirm the URLs for the two requests.

Answer (score 0):

A browser send 2 requests. 1 is your GET request and the 2nd one is an attempt to retrieve the favicon.

Comment: No I checked in Firefox, this is normal request to Servlet.

Comment: Only one request is sent ?

Comment: NO, pleas see my comment above. The reason is in IntelliJ Idea. If you are using tomcat "inside" he make double request in first time. If you disable auto-request when you are starting tomcat from Idea and make request from browser only one request appear.

Comment: Do you know how to disable auto-request in IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

It may because of your servlet annotation.
`@WebServlet ("/*")`
try with this 
`@WebServlet( displayName="Notification Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/yourservletpath"})`

Comment: No, it appear any time for any kind of servlet and JSP.